# WP7: Webbrowser control how to change image load coordinates

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, webbrowser-control

In my Windows phone app, i am using webbrowser control to load a local image to get the default pinch/zoom functionality from the browser control. I am using webcontrol navigate method to load the image from the app isolated storage. My browser control is 480x320 size and my local image is 1600x1200. always on load, image shows the first 480x320 size portion of the image and i can use pinch/zoom to navigate to the rest of the image.

My question is, is there any way to load my image and navigate to the other coordinates in my image instead of the top left corner of the image (eg: displaying portion of lower bottom of the image etc.) through programatically?

Answer (score 0):

put your image in an html page with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1 align="center"><img src="YOUR IMAGE" width="100%" longdesc="YOUR IMAGE" align="absmiddle"/>
</body>
</html>
```